# What is the difference between Flash Builder 4.5 Premium and Flash Builder 4.5 Premium for PHP?

Tags: apache-flex, comparison, flash-builder

I can't, for the life of me, find a decent feature comparison table of the **Flash Builder 4.5 Premium** and the **Flash Builder 4.5 Premium for PHP** (or it might be my poor site navigation skills). Can anyone detail their differences or point me to a table that states such?

What I had in mind was the **Flash Builder 4.5 Premium for PHP** is a trimmed down version of **Flash Builder 4.5 Premium** but apparently, the one with the **PHP** is more expensive by $100 than the one without.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/upgrade/details/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this link help you?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/introducing-flashbuilder45-php.html

See sections:
Easy Connection to PHP data services
Integrated Flex and PHP Debugging

For example, in my Flash Builder 4.5 projects, I see no help with connecting/debugging PHP data services.

Comment: So in essence, the one with the PHP thing is better than the one without?

Comment: @Shedo Chung-Hee Surashu, that depends on what you want to achieve. For example developers that use BlazeDS/LCDS will probably not use the php possibilities all too often.

Comment: So in the edition with the PHP feature added, a developer can't achieve the BlazeDS/LCDS one?

Comment: @Shedo Chung-Hee Surashu   In the PHP version, you can still work with BlazeDS/LCDS.

Comment: Oh okay then, so I guess the PHP one will be the way to go once I get to save enough money for purchasing it.